# Genetic Drift Simulator - Follow Up

Tags: javascript, simulation, underscore.js, genetic-algorithm

This question is a follow-up of a previous question of mine: [Genetic Drift Simulator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107038/genetic-drift-simulator).

Following the advice given in the last question, and some more general improvements, the code has been slimmed down a bit. The major one was implementing [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), which slimmed down a few of the loops into functions.

The config has identical properties to the last question, however, they've been renamed.

- `numGenerations`: the number of generations to iterate over. Can be number input or `infinite` to go until one population remains.
- `population`: an object containing the names of the populations and the amount of each.
- `drawAmount`: the amount of population to be surveyed.

```
var GeneticDriftSimulator = function (user_config) {
    this.config = _.defaults(user_config, {
        numGenerations: '5',
        population: {
            red: 50,
            blue: 50
        },
        drawAmount: 10
    });
};

GeneticDriftSimulator.prototype.run = function () {
    var ratioPopulation = this.config.population;
    var isIndefinite = (this.config.numGenerations == 'infinite');
    for (var i = 0; isIndefinite || i < this.config.numGenerations; i++) {
        if (Object.keys(ratioPopulation).length == 1) {
            console.log('Generation ' + i + ': One trait left: ' + Object.keys(ratioPopulation)[0]);
            break;
        }
        var population = [];
        for (var populationName in ratioPopulation) {
            for (var k = 0; k < ratioPopulation[populationName]; k++) {
                population.push(populationName);
            }
        }
        ratioPopulation = this.ProcessGeneration(population, config.drawAmount);

        var print_result = "Generation " + i + ": ";
        Object.keys(ratioPopulation).forEach(function (key) {
            print_result += key + ':' + ratioPopulation[key] + ' '
        });
        console.log(print_result);
    }
};

GeneticDriftSimulator.prototype.ProcessGeneration = function (population, drawAmount) {
    var temp_drawn = [];
    if (config.drawAmount >= population.length) {
        throw 'SimulationError: The DrawAmount is more than the Population.';
    }
    if (population.length % drawAmount != 0) {
        throw 'SimulationError: The DrawAmount cannot be evenly divided by Population';
    }

    temp_drawn = _.sample(population, drawAmount);
    var multiplier = population.length / drawAmount;
    return this.RatioCount(multiplier, temp_drawn);
};

GeneticDriftSimulator.prototype.RatioCount = function (multiplier, temp_drawn) {
    var final = {};
    _.each(temp_drawn, function (population) {
        for (var i = 0; i < multiplier; i++) {
            if (!(population in final)) {
                final[population] = 0;
            }
            final[population]++;
        }
    });
    return final;
}
```

with usage like the following:

> ```
> var config = {
>     numGenerations: 'infinite',
>     population: {
>         cats: 3e4,
>         dogs: 7e4,
>     },
>     drawAmount: 5e4
> };
> var simulation = new GeneticDriftSimulator(config);
> simulation.run();
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Bug

You accidentally use `config` instead of `this.config` sometimes:

```
    ratioPopulation = this.ProcessGeneration(population, config.drawAmount);

    if (config.drawAmount >= population.length) {
```

You're actually using the global `config` variable you have for testing:

```
var config = {
    numGenerations: 'infinite',
    population: {
        cats: 3e4,
        dogs: 7e4,
    },
    drawAmount: 5e4
};
```

Change its name or inline it to make sure you're not referencing it directly in `GeneticDriftSimulator`.

#### Code Review

```
if (Object.keys(ratioPopulation).length == 1)
```

You can use Underscore's `size`:

```
if (_.size(ratioPopulation) === 1)
```

---

```
Object.keys(ratioPopulation).forEach(function (key) {
```

Change to:

```
for(var key in ratioPopulation) {
```

---

The second argument of `processGeneration` is redundant, you can simply use `this.config`.

---

```
var temp_drawn = [];
```

There's no need to initialize this variable.

---

```
var final = {};
```

I prefer the name `result` for a variable that's returned by the function.

---

The `run` function both controls the looping and does some of the computation of each iteration (This is the reason it has the temporary variable `population` inside the loop). It's better to move the computation of `population` to `processGeneration` so that each function focuses only on one thing: `run` on the looping and `processGeneration` on the computation of the next generation.

This also gives you a nice symmetry: `processGeneration` takes an object and returns an object (both have the same structure), instead of taking an array and returning and object.

---

Many of your functions do multiple things:

- `run` controls the looping, but it also has some formatting logic.
- `processGeneration` calls the functions that constitue the steps of the iteration computation, but it also performs some of logic itself: the checks before the call to `sample` should really be made by `sample` itself (wrap the checks and the call to `_.sample` inside your own sample function).
- `ratioCount` both counts the population size of each trait and multiplies the counts.

You should extract each functionality into each own function, so each function does only one thing. Then the main code of `GeneticDriftSimulator` should look like this:

```
GeneticDriftSimulator.prototype.run = function () {
    var ratioPopulation = this.config.population;
    var isIndefinite = (this.config.numGenerations == 'infinite');
    for (var i = 0; isIndefinite || i < this.config.numGenerations; i++) {
        if (this.numberOfLeftTraits(ratioPopulation) === 1) {
            this.printOneTraitLeft(i, ratioPopulation);
            break;
        }

        ratioPopulation = this.processGeneration(ratioPopulation);
        this.printGeneration(i, ratioPopulation);
    }
};

GeneticDriftSimulator.prototype.processGeneration = function (ratioPopulation) {
    var population = this.buildPopulationArray(ratioPopulation);

    var populationSample = this.sample(population, this.config.drawAmount);
    var traitsCount = this.countTraits(populationSample);

    var multiplier = population.length / this.config.drawAmount;
    return this.multiplyCounts(traitsCount, multiplier);
};
```

(`sample` performs the checks and calls `_.sample`. `multiplyCounts` multiplies each value of the `traitsCount` object and can be implemented with `_.mapObject`. We presumably lost some performance by splitting `ratioCount`, but performance is probably not critical here and I'm guessing `ratioCount` wasn't the bottleneck anyway)

Notice how much easier it becomes to understand the logic of `run` and `processGeneration` when all other unrelated logic is in other functions.

---

After you do this, you'll notice the `run` function passes `i` and `ratioPopulation` to all of the methods it calls. This suggests they are a part of the state of the simulation and thus should be instance variables:

```
GeneticDriftSimulator.prototype.run = function () {
    var isIndefinite = (this.config.numGenerations == 'infinite');

    this.generationCount = 0;
    this.ratioPopulation = this.config.population;

    while(isIndefinite || this.generationCount < this.config.numGenerations) {
        if (this.numberOfLeftTraits() === 1) {
            this.printOneTraitLeft();
            break;
        }

        this.processGeneration();
        this.printGeneration();

        this.generationCount++;
    }
};
```

(The methods called by `run` no longer accept arguments but use `this.generationCount` and `this.ratioPopulation` instead. `processGeneration` was changed to modify `this.ratioPopulation` instead of returning a value. I recommend that `buildPopulationArray` still gets `ratioPopulation` as an argument because it's a helper function for an intermediate step and it's nice when your helper functions are independent of state.)

Answer (score 6):

A few things to point out in retrospect:

- There's inconsistent quotation marks everywhere
- Lines like the following are confusing and hard to read: `print_result += key + ':' + ratioPopulation[key] + ' '`
- These (`throw`) should be `throw new Error` as it includes a stack trace.
- Don't use snake case (`temp_drawn`) use camel case (`tempDrawn`)
- Be careful about using truthy value checks like (`population.length % drawAmount != 0`) as it can cause issues relating to booleans, for example `false == 0` will return true, but `false === 0` will return false. See [Truthy and Falsy: When All is Not Equal in JavaScript](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) for more information and examples.
- `run` doesn't match the case of the other functions, it should be `Run`.
- `k < ratioPopulation[populationName];`: declare the length as a variable within the `for` loop as it gets rid of the constant `length` checking which can strain when you have a really large array.
- You should consider using an array here instead `var final = {};` as it may reduce logic on the loops.

Answer (score 2):

Your method names should begin with a small letter e.g `processGeneration` instead of `ProcessGeneration`.

You could make the `print_result` creation arguably a bit more readable as follows:

```
var format = function (trait) {
    return trait + ":" + ratioPopulation[trait];
};

var traits = Object.keys(ratioPopulation);

var print_result = "Generation " + i + ": " + traits.map(format).join(" ");
```

I would be tempted to have a method specifically for printing the result.
If you changed `ProcessGeneration` to not return a value, but just set `this.ratioPopulation = this.RatioCount(multiplier, temp_drawn);` you could try

```
GeneticDriftSimulator.prototype.printResult = function (generationIndex) {
    var ratioPopulation = this.ratioPopulation;

    var format = function (trait) {
        return trait + ":" + ratioPopulation[trait];
    };

    var traits = Object.keys(ratioPopulation);
    var result = "Generation " + generationIndex + ": " + traits.map(format).join(" ");
    console.log(result);
}
```

and then you could have

```
  this.processGeneration(population, config.drawAmount);
  this.printResult(i);
```

Actually, where does that `config` come from in the `this.processGeneration()` call? It doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. Do you need to pass it at all? Why not just access `this.config.drawAmount` in `processGeneration`?

You should get into to the habit of using `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=`. You can read about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-JavaScript-comparisons).

You can change

```
if (Object.keys(ratioPopulation).length == 1) {
        console.log('Generation ' + i + ': One trait left: ' + Object.keys(ratioPopulation)[0]);
        break;
    }
```

to

```
 var traits = Object.keys(ratioPopulation);
 if (traits.length === 1) {
        console.log('Generation ' + i + ': One trait left: ' + traits[0]);
        break;
    }
```

so that you only call `Object.keys` once.

You could move

```
    var population = [];
    for (var populationName in ratioPopulation) {
        for (var k = 0; k < ratioPopulation[populationName]; k++) {
            population.push(populationName);
        }
    }
    ratioPopulation = this.ProcessGeneration(population, config.drawAmount);
```

into its own method.

```
  //In the constructor 
  this.ratioPopulation = this.config.population;

  // new method
  GeneticDriftSimulator.prototype.buildPopulation = function () {
      var population = [];
      var ratioPopulation = this.ratioPopulation;

      for (var populationName in ratioPopulation) {
        for (var k = 0; k < ratioPopulation[populationName]; k++) {
            population.push(populationName);
        }
      }

      return population;

  }
```

and call it in `processGeneration`.

```
GeneticDriftSimulator.prototype.processGeneration = function () {
    var population = this.buildPopulation();
    var drawAmount = this.config.drawAmount;

    //etc;
}
```

the call in `run` is simplified to

```
this.processGeneration();
this.printResult(i);
```